# Can the mechanism of `java.security.AccessControlContext` be generalised to include any context information?

Tags: java, hadoop, access-control, java-security

This question is derived from reading Hadoop credential management: In Hadoop 3.3+, function `UserGroupInformation.doAs` can introduce an "execution scope", that allows some context information to be modified when being called inside the scope:

```
    import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation
    import java.security.PrivilegedAction

    val ugi = UserGroupInformation.createUserForTesting("abc", Array("a", "b", "c"))

    val u = UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser
    println(u)

    val t1 = Thread.currentThread()

    val t2 = ugi.doAs {
      new PrivilegedAction[Thread] {
        override def run(): Thread = {

          val u = UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser // alternatively, calling it in subroutine won't change its outcome
          println(u)

          val t = Thread.currentThread()

          t
        }
      }
    }

    assert(t1 == t2)

/*
execution result:
os-user (auth:SIMPLE)
abc (auth:SIMPLE)

*/
```

It minimally depends on Java Security, which appears to implement a call-stack based approach and is agnostic to local thread, fibre, or coroutine, as implied in the following Java security implementation:

```
    public static AccessControlContext getContext()
    {
        AccessControlContext acc = getStackAccessControlContext();
        if (acc == null) {
            // all we had was privileged system code. We don't want
            // to return null though, so we construct a real ACC.
            return new AccessControlContext(null, true);
        } else {
            return acc.optimize();
        }
    }
```

For scoped context information control, this appears to be the most lightweight approach I have seen in any JVM libraries: the underlying function can use any subroutine, without relying on boilerplate function parameter, macro or auto-completion like in alternative implementations (e.g. https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/ca-contextual-abstractions-intro.html).

My question is: Had this approach be used to control other context information? If not, why is it only reserved for Java security?

Comment: I would not put effort into researching it. AccessControlContext is a deprecated class in JDK 17: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/AccessControlContext.html

Comment: @aled wow ... dropped without replacement. I wonder how Hadoop can react to this :->

Comment: I would assume they removed the code that used it, or are planning to do it.

Comment: they can't, access control is everywhere in HDFS (& other components but they probably won't matter these days)